# Using .click() twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function right now is set to animate a pop up window on mouse over and close the pop up window when the mouse leaves the area.

**I would like call .click() twice**. I've been playing around with `.click()` and can only get it to function once since when used twice it tries to call both `.click()` functions at the same time.

My functions are

```
$('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
}
```

and

```
.bind('mouseleave',function(){
}
```

I've tried putting click into one of the functions,

```
$('#sdt_menu > li').bind('click',function(){
}
```

Which works great but I can't use it in both of them so I'm thinking I need to rewrite and put in new functions for each .click() but I still can't figure out how to use it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the default `toggle` function from jquery, the bareboens of it would be

```
$("#sdt_menu > li").toggle(
    function(){
        // hide...
    },
    function(){
        // show...
    }
);
```

Where `std_menu > li` is what I supply and then entered in my functions to the two toggle functions